# What's the Kendall Tau's distance between these 2 rankings?

Tags: metric, kendall-tau

ranking i: {3, 1, 2}

ranking j: {2, 1, 3}

I am referring to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) page here, and to calculate the Kendall distance, I just need to count the number of times the values in ranking i are in the opposite order of the values in ranking j.

3 < 1 in ranking i, but 3 > 1 in ranking j

3 < 2 in ranking i, but 3 > 2 in ranking j

1 < 2 in ranking i, but 1 > 2 in ranking j

There are 3 switches, so the Kendall distance is 3. However when I call a function to calculate the Kendall's distance in R, it returns 1. What's the correct Kendall's distance between these 2 rankings?

Comment: The wiki says the distance is the total number of discordant pairs of observations (that is, it is Q in the formula of Gamma or Kendall's tau). Consider the pairs of observations (columns): `i(3>1) and j(2>1) = concordant`; `i(1<2) and j(1<3)` = concordant; `i(3>2) but j(2<3) = discordant`. One discordant pair.

Comment: If it's [3,1,2] vs [2,1,3] the number of discordant pairs here is 3 out of 3.
If you use Python's scipy Kendall’s tau function to calculate the correlation coefficient you'll get -1.
The coefficient is defined as the ratio of concordant pairs minus the discordant pairs, in this case it's 0/3 - 3/3
Unless you're looking at it as indices and values, (let's say indices are letters) than:
ranking i: a-3, b-1, c-2 = b-1, c-2, a-3
ranking j: a-2, b-1, c-3 = b-1, a-2, c-3
In that case the distance is 1.
So perhaps the function in R looks at it this way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kendall tau distance in your case is, indeed, 1.

See the following python code:

```
import itertools

def kendallTau(A, B):
    pairs = itertools.combinations(range(0, len(A)), 2)

    distance = 0

    for x, y in pairs:
        a = A[x] - A[y]
        b = B[x] - B[y]

        # if discordant (different signs)
        if (a * b < 0):
            distance += 1

    return distance


ranking_i = [3, 1, 2]
ranking_j = [2, 1, 3]
assert kendallTau(ranking_i, ranking_j) == 1
```

Comment: that wrong, the distance is 3.  See other answers

Comment: The function works ok, there's just confusion between orderings and ranks. The ordered list of objects 3 > 1 > 2 posed in the original question translates to assigned ranks of [2, 3, 1] (i.e. object 3 is ranked first, object 1 second, and object 2 third). Likewise, the list 2 > 1 > 3 takes assigned ranks of [2, 1, 3]. This answer assumes the ordered lists ('rankings') provided are themselves ranks assigned to objects (e.g. assuming in 'ranking i' that object 1 is ranked third, object 2 first, etc). Setting `ranking_i = [2, 3, 1]` and `ranking_j = [2, 1, 3]` yields the correct distance (3).

Answer (score 10):

The wrong answer got accepted!  The correct answer is 3.

From Wikipedia:
Kendall tau distance is also called **bubble-sort distance** since it is equivalent to the number of swaps that the bubble sort algorithm would take to place one list in the same order as the other list.

```
import itertools

def kendall_tau_distance(order_a, order_b):
    pairs = itertools.combinations(range(1, len(order_a)+1), 2)
    distance = 0
    for x, y in pairs:
        a = order_a.index(x) - order_a.index(y)
        b = order_b.index(x) - order_b.index(y)
        if a * b < 0:
            distance += 1
    return distance

print kendall_tau_distance([3,1,2], [2,1,3])
3
```

Comment: I think you need to look again at the comment under the original question for the definition of Kendall distance.

Comment: I think that the definition of Kendall tau distance in the comment under the original question is wrong.
its not whats is in 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance 


The Kendall tau rank distance between two rank orders is the total number of rank disagreements over all unordered pairs.

Comment: @Cohensius It clearly says in the mathematical definition of $K(\tau_1 \tau_2)$ that you have to index the lists, also, in OP's question, you only need one single swap to make one list the same as the other (you swap indexes 1 and 3).

Comment: ...counts the number of pairwise disagreements between two ranking lists:
in the OP example:

in ranking i: 3<1 while in ranking j: 1<3
in ranking i: 1<2 while in ranking j: 2<1
in ranking i: 3<2 while in ranking j: 2<3

Thats 3 pairwise disagreements

Comment: @Ash the swaps need to be between adjacent items, so 3 is correct

Answer (score 1):

The Kendall tau distance in this instance is 3. It is also known as Kemeny distance. See [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20026529) and [here](https://cris.maastrichtuniversity.nl/portal/files/1523507/guid-5bc99848-9276-4cd5-95fc-88162618ab20-ASSET1.0).

In some fields rankings are also allowed to have ties, therefore the Kemeny could be considered as a distance of 6 instead of 3. That's a confusion that arises quite often. But in your situation it *is* 3 because ties are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Kendell tau distance is the number of swaps which needs to be done for making the two lists the same. It can also be considered as a variant of Insertion Sort, where each swap adds +1 to Kendell distance.

Comment: You don't answer the OP question.  What's the correct Kendall's distance between these 2 rankings?